# Puzzled about printf output

Tags: c, floating-point, printf

While using printf with %d as format specifier and giving a float as an argument e.g, 2.345, it prints 1546188227. So, I understand that it may be due to the conversion of single point float precision format to simple decimal format. But when we print 2.000 with the %d as format specifier, then why it prints 0 only ?
Please help.

Comment: Post the actual source. Looks like your code may have the arguments messed up in `printf`. Also, note that `%d` is for printing integers; `%f` is what you want for floats.

Answer (score 4):

Format specifier `%d` can only be used with values of type `int` (and compatible types). Trying to use `%d` with `float` or any other types produces undefined behavior. That's the only explanation that truly applies here. From the language point of view the output you see is essentially random. And you are not guaranteed to get any output at all.

If you are still interested in investigating the specific reason for the output you see (however little sense it makes), you'll have to perform a platform-specific investigation, because the actual behavior depends critically on various implementation details. And you are not even mentioning your platform in your post.

In any case, as a side note, note that it is impossible to pass `float` values as variadic arguments to variadic functions. `float` values in such cases are always converted to `double` and passed as `double`. So in your case it is `double` values you are attempting to print. Behavior is still undefined though.

Comment: But, although undefined behaviour, it explains the output. The low order 32 bits of the mantissa of the `double` 2.345 are `0x5c28f5c3 = 1546188227`, and the low order 32 bits of the mantissa of the `double` 2.0 are all 0. So `printf` just interprets four bytes of the `double` as an `int`, and the platform is little-endian, so the four bytes taken are the low-order 32 bits of the mantissa.

Answer (score 1):

Go [here](http://babbage.cs.qc.cuny.edu/IEEE-754.old/Decimal.html), enter `2.345`, click "rounded". Observe 64-bit hex value: `4002C28F5C28F5C3`. Observe that `1546188227` is `0x5c28f5c3`.

Now repeat for 2.00. Observe that 64-bit hex value is `4000000000000000`

P.S. When you say that you give a *float* argument, what you apparently mean is that you give a *double* argument.

Answer (score 1):

Here what ISO/IEC 9899:1999 standard $7.19.6 states:

```
If a conversion specification is invalid, the behavior is undefined.239)
If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding conversion
specification, the behavior is undefined.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to make it print integer values, cast the floats to ints in the call:

```
printf("ints: %d %d", (int) 2.345, (int) 2.000);
```

Otherwise, use the floating point format identifier:

```
printf("floats: %f %f", 2.345, 2.000);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use printf with wrong format specifier for the corresponding argument, the result is undefined behavior. It could be anything and may differ from one implementation to another. Only correct use of format specified has defined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

First a small nitpick: The literal 2.345 is actually of the type double, not float, and besides, even a float, such as the literal 2.345f, would be converted to double when used as an argument to a function that takes a variable number of arguments, such as printf.

But what happens here is that the (typically) 64 bits of the double value is sent to printf, and then it interprets (typically) 32 of those bits as an integer value. So it just happens that those bits were zero.

According to the standard, this is what is called undefined behavior: The compiler is allowed to do anything at all.